# Where can I get the source code from apple's GLImageProcessing example?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I was reading on a blog that there's a GLImageProcessing example from apple. I couldn't find it on apple's site. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/index.html